# Как отнять 1 месяц от даты

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть запрос

```
WITH crimes_count AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT *
      FROM
        (SELECT category,
                MONTH AS mth,
                         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY category, MONTH
                                       ORDER BY MONTH)
         FROM streetlevelcrimes) AS a
      GROUP BY a.category,
               a.mth,
               a.count
      ORDER BY a.mth) AS b)
SELECT *
FROM crimes_count AS a
JOIN crimes_count AS b ON a.category = b.category
WHERE FORMAT(a.mth, 'YYYY-MM') = add_months(FORMAT(a.mth, 'YYYY-MM'), -1)  # Вот тут мне нужно отнять 1 месяц
```

Дата хранится в формате TEXT и выглядит следующим образом: `'2018-01'`, `('YYYY-MM')`.
Мне надо конвертировать текст в дату и отнять от этой даты месяц, по данному запросу выдает ошибку

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit
type casts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужны функции `to_date` и `to_char`:

```sql
SELECT to_char(to_date('2018-01', 'YYYY-MM') - INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM');
```

Результат:

```
 to_char 
---------
 2017-12
(1 row)
```

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо Вам большое!